# XUnit and MSTest returnig different values. Why?

Tags: c#, mstest, xunit

I am trying to unit test this code, but I am getting different results when using MSTest and XUnit. Why? Does anyone have any idea?

```
public static string DecryptString(string cipherText)
{
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InitVector);
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(StrEncriptyPass, null);
    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);

    return result;
}
```

Using MSTest it works fine and the decryptedActual variable gets this value:  "Testando encriptação".

```
[TestMethod()]
public void DecryptStringTest_DecryptString_ReturnsEqual()
{
    var decryptedActual = DecryptString("r2AegGm+zAYmaRL4i+62O2IJrhcHyPsWxHoDZ7bMimI=");
    var esperado = "Testando encriptação";

    Assert.AreEqual(decryptedActual, esperado);
}
```

But if I use XUnit, it does not retun the same result. The decryptedActual variable gets this value:  "Testando encript". It is missing "ação" from the decripted string.

```
[Fact]
public void DecryptStringTest_DecryptString_ReturnsEqual()
{
    var decryptedActual = DecryptString("r2AegGm+zAYmaRL4i+62O2IJrhcHyPsWxHoDZ7bMimI=");
    var esperado = "Testando encriptação";

    Assert.Equal(decryptedActual, esperado);
}
```

While debugging I found that this line of code:

```
byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
```

is the one returning different values with XUnit, but why? cipherTextBytes.Length returns 32, but plainTextBytes gets filled only until index 15 with XUnit and until 21 with STest, as we can see on the images:

#### XUnit Screenshot

[image: XUnit]

#### MS Test Screenshot

[image: MSTest]

Somehow XUnit is affecting the way that function is working.
Keysize= 256. InitVector is a 16 character string and as StrEncriptyPass it can be text with that size.

Comment: This might just be a typo, but there is an extra character after one of the closing `}` characters in your first code snippet. Was that intentional?

Comment: Which framework version are you targeting in the xunit version? Are you changing any of the default culture settings in the .NET Framework?

Comment: Just a typo.. Version 2.4.1. Didn't change anything. I just installed and tried to use it.

Comment: I realize this is unrelated, but the stream objects should be used inside a `using (...) { ... }` block to ensure they get closed and disposed of if an exception gets thrown.

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you using for your MSTest and xUnit test projects?

Comment: At first I was targeting .NET Framework 4.8 for both, because I just removed the MSTest and add the XUnit to the project, and I was getting different results. Now I decide to create a new project for XUnit that targets .NET framework 6.0, and it is still giving me a different result.